# Expensive flatMap() operation on streams originating from Stream.emits()

Tags: scala, fs2

I just encountered an issue with degrading fs2 performance using a stream of strings to be written to a file via `text.utf8encode`. I tried to change my source to use chunked strings to increase performance, but the observation was performance degradation instead.

As far as I can see, it boils down to the following: Invoking `flatMap` on a stream that originates from `Stream.emits()` can be very expensive. Time usage seems to be exponential based on the size of the sequence passed to Stream.emits(). The code snippet below shows an example:

```scala
/*
    Test done with scala 2.11.11 and fs2 version 0.10.0-M7.
 */

val rangeSize = 20000
val integers = (1 to rangeSize).toVector

// Note that the last flatMaps are just added to show extreme load for streamA.
val streamA = Stream.emits(integers).flatMap(Stream.emit(_))
val streamB = Stream.range(1, rangeSize + 1).flatMap(Stream.emit(_))

streamA.toVector  // Uses approx. 25 seconds (!)
streamB.toVector  // Uses approx. 15 milliseconds
```

Is this a bug, or should usage of Stream.emits() for large sequences be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR: Allocations.

Longer answer:

Interesting question. I ran a JFR profile on both methods separately, and looked at the results. First thing which immediately attracted my eye was the amount of *allocations*.

`Stream.emit`:

[image: Stream.emit allocations]

`Stream.range`:

[image: Stream.range allocations]

We can see that `Stream.emit` allocates a significant amount of `Append` instances, which are the concrete implementation of `Catenable[A]`, which is the type used in `Stream.emit` to fold:

```
private[fs2] final case class Append[A](left: Catenable[A], right: Catenable[A]) extends Catenable[A]
```

This actually comes from the implementation of how `Catenable[A]` implemented `foldLeft`:

```
foldLeft(empty: Catenable[B])((acc, a) => acc :+ f(a))
```

Where `:+` allocates a new `Append` object for each element. This means we're at least generating 20000 such `Append` objects.

There is also a hint in the documentation of `Stream.range` about how it produces a *single chunk* instead of dividing the stream further, which may be bad if this was a big range we're generating:

```
/**
 * Lazily produce the range `[start, stopExclusive)`. If you want to produce
 * the sequence in one chunk, instead of lazily, use
 * `emits(start until stopExclusive)`.
 *
 * @example {{{
 * scala> Stream.range(10, 20, 2).toList
 * res0: List[Int] = List(10, 12, 14, 16, 18)
 * }}}
 */
def range(start: Int, stopExclusive: Int, by: Int = 1): Stream[Pure,Int] =
  unfold(start){i =>
    if ((by > 0 && i < stopExclusive && start < stopExclusive) ||
        (by < 0 && i > stopExclusive && start > stopExclusive))
      Some((i, i + by))
    else None
}
```

You can see that there is no additional wrapping here, only the integers that get emitted as part of the range. On the other hand, `Stream.emits` creates an `Append` object for every element in the sequence, where we have a `left` containing the tail of the stream, and `right` containing the current value we're at.

Is this a bug? I would say no, but I would definitely open this up as a performance issue to the `fs2` library maintainers.